# How to ignore the back button history of browser while click on back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html5-history

I want to ignore browser back button history, instead of I want to call Ajax function and as per it redirect to get response url.

Here, I just make a table, when I click on the table cell it display the detail data on this page make through Ajax. Above the table also make anchor tag, when you hit there it apply reverse process, means display main table.

But I also want apply reverse process on browser back button. for that I have to ignore browser back history.

Following are the overview of table redirection structure.

Table Redirection :

Main Table (Name : Employee list)-> Table 2 (Name : Particular Employee detail) -> Table 3 (Name : designation detail)

Reverse Redirection (Anchor Tags) :

> All The list >
>
> All The list > Employee1_Detail >
>
> All The list > Employee1_Detail > Designation1_Detail >

1) Click on the Designation1_Detail, it redirect to Table2.

2) Click on the Employee1_Detail, it redirect to Main Table.

3) And all the list is default anchor.

This process is also want to apply on back button history. when user on the designation table and press back button, user may redirect to particular employee table, again press back it redirect to employee list table and now press back button user redirect to browser last history.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/History

Comment: @A.Wolff just look into it.

Comment: Look specifically here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries & so https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_replaceState()_method

Comment: @A.Wolff , Thank you so much it is really helpful for me. from just I got little idea and finally got my goal. I really appreciate for your help.